# Is there any existing library that has matlab functions implemented in C/CPP/Obj-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, matlab, porting

I am using an algorithm that is only implemented in Matlab.

However I need to run it with gcc, once I do not have the needed Matlab licenses neither for server or for porting the code.

Sp, I'm trying to make my own implementation of the algorithm in Objective-C.
This way I'd like to know if there is already any existing library that has (at least a set of) Matlab functions implemented.

ATM I'm making the Matlab functions by myself, which is turning to be a very time-consuming task.

Thanks.

Comment: It's this one:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18244-adaptive-affinity-propagation-clustering/content/apcluster.m

Comment: I'm a C++ and Matlab user. For my Matrix/Vector-related things I use Eigen in C++. Of course, Eigen does not provide all of what the Matlab toolboxes offer. But it offers quite a lot w.r.t. linear algebra and the syntax is bearable thanks to overloadable operators in C++. Then, there is also GSL (GNU Scientific Library) which only comes with a C interface as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe GNU Octave is something you could use. It's an open source Matlab-clone with a nice level of compatibility. I use it at home occasionally because I don't have a private copy of Matlab there.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It doesn't need to be specifically in Objective-C, as the title suggests. However, I've made this particular choice because the algorithm will run in an iOS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good and bad news - there is a library specifically designed to enable translations of Matlab code to C++ - [MatrixLib](http://www.psatellite.com/matrixlib/index.php) from Princeton Satelite Systems. [I know of this since I use to work on it when at that company :-)]. However, its not cheap. You can read the documentation online, and you might be able to negotiate a discount for one reason or the other.

When there I specially used this to do a huge Matlab script to C++ so its definitely targeted towards that use.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything unusual or exotic used in the code at the link you provided, so it should be fairly simple to reimplement if you just have a linear algebra library. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is pretty good, so is Boost's [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), though uBLAS is reported to be a bit slow.

I recommend you read [this StackExchange post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library) for a fairly comprehensive comparison of the different ones available.